# nhibernate complex query of sql with a group by ROLLUP() of permenant table union all derived query

Tags: sql, sql-server, nhibernate

How would you convert the following sql that contains a case count, group by, union all to  nhibernate?
This complex sqql with  a  group by ROLLUP() of permanent table union all derived query columns

```html
select 
CASE
         WHEN GROUPING([BUSINESS_UNIT]) = 1 THEN 'Total'
         ELSE [BUSINESS_UNIT]
       END [BUSINESS_UNIT]
     , SUM(InjuryIllnessTtlCount) InjuryIllnessTtlCount
 from (
select i.INCIDENT_ID
      ,b.BUSINESS_UNIT
    ,case 
        when (i.INJURY_ILLNESS_TYPE_ID=4  ) then 1  --'Injury/Illness (Near Miss with High Severity Potential)' 
        else 0
    end as InjuryIllnessTtlCount
from tblIncident i
join tblBUSINESS_UNIT b on i.BUS_UNIT_ID = b.BUS_UNIT_ID
--where (CONVERT(varchar(10),i.create_dt, 111) between '2015/01/12' and '2015/05/12') 
union all
select 0 incident_id
      
      ,b.BUSINESS_UNIT
      ,0 InjuryIllnessTtlCount
 from 
tblBUSINESS_UNIT b 
) abc
group by ROLLUP(abc.BUSINESS_UNIT)
```

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to this complicated queries, the conversion to NHibernate either not possible or does not worth it. So my two cents is to go with,

```
var query = <your query>;

var session = sessionFactory.OpenSession();
var result =session.CreateSQLQuery(query)
                .List();
```

Where the Query is directly executed.